# Query count and count fetchArray not same in Doctrine and Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have got a bug. When I count the query method and count the result  of fetchArray method but the result of them are not same. So I get an error when fetch the result of query in backend generator in Symfony 1.4.

The query what I have used below:

```
    $alias = 's';
    $query = VtArticleTable::getInstance()->createQuery('va');
    $query->innerJoin("va.sfGuardUserCreatedBy s");
    $query->innerJoin("va.ArticleCategory ac");
    $query->select("$alias.id AS user_id,  COALESCE($alias.phone, ' ') AS phone_user ,       COALESCE($alias.email_address, ' ') AS email_user , COALESCE($alias.first_name, ' ') AS first_name_user, "
            . "COALESCE($alias.last_name, ' ') AS last_name_user, $alias.username AS user_name,  COALESCE(ac.name, ' ') AS category_name,"
            . " va.type AS article_type, COUNT(*) AS total_article ");

    $query->groupBy("ac.id, va.type, s.username");
    $query->where('ac.id IS NOT NULL');
    $query->andWhere('va.id IS NOT NULL');
    $query->andWhere('s.id IS NOT NULL');
    $query->orderBy('ac.updated_at DESC');

    $query->count() = 61
    count($query->fetchArray()) = 51
```

PS : VtArticle and VtArticleCategory have many to many relation.

How can I get a right result with query in generator?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to count then inside the controller?
Anyway, with a quick look I notice that you miss the execute() method before the count() method.

So you should print
$query->execute()->count()